# how to toggle all divs when click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, show-hide

needs to close (hide) all .body divs =? ( div.body{ display:none } ? )

needs to close (hide) all .body Open divs, when click on the .button

needs to open just closest .body div, Open when click on the .button

needs to change .button icon ( Negative or Positive Icon ) when click on the .button

### HTML

```
<div class="box">

  <div class="header">

    <a href="#" class="button">

      <span class="fa positive"></span>

    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="body">

  </div>

</div>
```

### JQUERY

```
jQuery('.button').on('click', function() {

  jQuery('.body').close();

  jQuery(this).closest(".body, .header").toggle(); // Edit 

  jQuery('span').toggleClass('negative');

  jQuery(this).parents().find('.body').toggle() // i test it, doesn't work

});
```

### STYLE

```
.body {
  display:none;
}

.button .positive:before {
  content : "sample ( + )";
}

.button .negative:before {
  content : 'sample ( - )';
}
```

[image]

Comment: This will not solve all of your issues, but for starters, `jQuery.closest()` is not valid. `.closest()` is a function on a jQuery element, not jQuery itself. It would need to say `jQuery(this).closest(...)`

Comment: don't try to reinvent the wheel, learn from those who did it already: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: @webeno I cant use Bootstrap in my Project or any frameworks, thx

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean you implementing bootstrap, rather review the relevant code and copy it...

Comment: @webeno That's more trouble than it's worth for a simple accordion. You can achieve this effect in like 5 lines of code ;)

Comment: @DelightedD0D let's agree that we don't agree ;) it's not exactly 5 lines, and learning from the pros by analysing well tested code is always the best way to do it, of course that would prevent you collecting some points here on SO ;)

Comment: @webeno consider us agreed. That said, I could be convinced to sway to your way of thinking. Maybe it would help if we actually take a look at the bootstrap code that handles this type of behaviour? This way we can evaluate how they did it. You might have a look at the bootstrap plugin [colapse.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/js/collapse.js), but do note that it requires the bootstrap plugin  [transition.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/js/transition.js), collectively about 200 lines of code. I guess you could be right ;) Then again, maybe *7* lines will do..

Comment: @DelightedD0D I give you that I haven't actually taken a look at the code, and it isn't always easy to analyse what exactly is influencing specific elements on a site (a script visualizer tool does exist aiding this), so my statement was really just a general one, hence I only added it as a comment... ;)

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $btn = $(this);
  $('.body').hide();
  $('.box .negative').removeClass('negative').addClass('positive');

  $btn.closest('.box').find('.body').toggle(); 
  $btn.find('span').toggleClass('negative');

});
```

```css
.body {
  display:none;
}

.button .positive:before {
  content : "sample ( + )";
}

.button .negative:before {
  content : 'sample ( - )';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"> 
  <div class="header"> 
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <span class="fa positive"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
   some text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <span class="fa positive"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
   some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had the same solution, but you beat me to it. Only thing I'll say is that you can simplify `$('.box button span')` to `$('.box .negative')`